# How can I return values from a given list using a function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, function

I have a function which converts Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius

```
def temp_to_celcius(temp):
    return ((temp-32.0)*5.0)/9.0
```

It takes a column from DataFrame containing list of Fahrenheit temperatures, e.g.:

```
table['temp'][:5]

0    30.0
1    30.0
2    30.0
3    30.0
4    30.0
Name: temp, dtype: float64
```

And returns amended list of temperatures:

```
temp_to_celcius(table['temp'][:5])
    
0   -1.111111
1   -1.111111
2   -1.111111
3   -1.111111
4   -1.111111
Name: temp, dtype: float64
```

But how can I amend my function in order to return the **values** in the second column itself as a list like this:

```
[-1.11111111 -1.11111111 -1.11111111 -1.11111111 -1.11111111]
```

but not an indexed column with a list of temperatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas`' DataFrame columns are `pandas.Series` you might just provide `pandas.Series` as argument to `list` to get `plain` list, consider following example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3]})
def triple(x):
    return list(x*3)
triple_values = triple(df['col1'])
print(triple_values)
```

output

```
[3, 6, 9]
```

or use `pandas.Series`' `.tolist` method

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3]})
def triple(x):
    return (x*3).tolist()
triple_values = triple(df['col1'])
print(triple_values)
```

output

```
[3, 6, 9]
```